# Bring the object forward

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to bring the white dot in front of the axis. How can I do this without removing the "axis on top" code?

current:
[image]

I want this:
[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[grid=both,ymin=-5,ymax=5,xmax=5,xmin=-5,xticklabel=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,axis on top,
               minor tick num=1,axis lines = middle,xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,label style =
               {at={(ticklabel cs:1.1)}}]
   \draw[fill=white,thick] (0,3.4) circle (1.6pt);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can draw the circle out of `axis` but using cs coordinates.

Comment: hmm how? @Sigur

Comment: It's caused by option `axis on top`. Do you really need this option?

Comment: yes @muzimuzhiZ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option `axis on top` makes axis staff to be drawn on top of "main plotting" (unofficial name). It seems you can set layered graphics by `set layers=axis on top` and then put your drawing on a most foreground layer, which is `axis foreground` when `axis on top` is set.

See more info in `pgfplots`'s package manual, doc for `set layers` and `/pgfplots/layers/axis on top`.

```tex
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[grid=both,ymin=-5,ymax=5,xmax=5,xmin=-5,xticklabel=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,
               minor tick num=1,axis lines = middle,xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,label style =
               {at={(ticklabel cs:1.1)}},
               set layers=axis on top]
    \addplot expression {x};   % to check axis IS on top of plotting
    \addplot expression {3.5}; % and `\draw` is on top of of axis
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{axis foreground}
      \draw[fill=white,thick] (0,3.4) circle (1.6pt);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `set layers` (the same as `set layers=default`) sets the default order of layers. OP want to have the `axis on top` order. I am having trouble making it work.

Comment: @hpekristiansen Seems `set layers=axis on top` works.

Answer (score 0):

In the `axis` you can save the position:

```
\coordinate (foo) at (axis cs:0,3.4);
```

Then, out of `axis` you can draw anything you want on that position. For example:

```
\draw[fill=white,thick] (foo) circle (1.6pt);
```

[image]

### MWE

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[grid=both,ymin=-5,ymax=5,xmax=5,xmin=-5,xticklabel=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,axis on top,
               minor tick num=1,axis lines = middle,xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,label style =
               {at={(ticklabel cs:1.1)}}]
   \coordinate (foo) at (axis cs:0,3.4);
  \end{axis}
   \draw[fill=white,thick] (foo) circle (1.6pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: is not working:(

Comment: @Pitaya88, see the MWE above.